# Parse JSON in Objective-C from REST API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsjsonserialization

I am facing an issue when trying to parse this sample JSON coming from a REST API using `NSJSONSerialization`.

I am using option `NSJSONReadingallowfragment` but it's not getting converted to JSON, it is still in `NSString`.

Error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e53827600".

```
[
  {
    "TeamLeadID":57,
    "Name":"Baird Tim",
    "AssignmentUser":"C",
    "AssDetails":[
      {
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJECG8HC685188",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"T"
      },
      {
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFBG3HC699233",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"T"
      },{
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFBG6HC688985",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"T"
      },
      {
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFDJ2HC678401",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"T"
      },
      {
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFDJ2HC707329",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"T"
      },
      {
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFFG0HC669486",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"T"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "TeamLeadID":75,
    "Name":"Farran Alicia",
    "AssignmentUser":"O",
    "AssDetails":[
      {
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJECG8HC685188",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"Q"
      },{
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFBG3HC699233",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"Q"
      },{
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFBG6HC688985",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"Q"
      },{
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFDJ2HC678401",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"Q"
      },{
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFDJ2HC707329",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"Q"
      },{
        "NoOfVINs":"1C4RJFFG0HC669486",
        "HoldID_FK":402,
        "HoldNumber":"2208",
        "HoldDescription":"R OCT. CPA REJECTS",
        "UserType":"Q"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Hoping for an earliest response.

Comment: Which kind of issue are you having?

Comment: your json data is valid then what kind of issue your are facing ?

Comment: Ian getting error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e53827600"

Comment: Iam using option NSJSONReadingallowfragment but its not getting converted in to json it still in NSString , therefore facing issue in parsing the data?

Answer (score -1):

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &jsonError];

if (!jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
   }
}
```